# Find average value of this function

Tags: calculus, integration

There is a function $z=f(x, y)=\sqrt{s^2-x^2-y^2}$ where f is a continuous function and $f \geq 0$ in the region $D$.

The average value, $\bar{z}$ is $$\frac{1}{\text{Area of }D}\iint_D f(x, y)dA$$

At the same time, $s \geq 0$ is a constant where $D=\{(x, y):x^2+y^2\leq s^2\}$.

Question: show the average value of $f$ on the region $D$ is $\bar{z}$, where $\bar{z}=\dfrac{2s}{3}$.

So I now need to calculate the area of $D$ and the integral of $f(x, y)$. Because $\bar{z}$ is $$\dfrac{1}{\text{Area of }D}\iint_D f(x, y)dA$$

The area is easy, even though we don't know the exact value of $s$, the radius is $s$. This converts to polar coordinates, $\int_{2\pi}^{0}\int_{0}^{s}r$, $r$ is the radius.

What about the function $f(x, y)$? How do I find $\iint f(x, y)$?

Comment: What about using polar coordinates once again?

Comment: You asked this question earlier that was closed. I still do not see any further effort than just writing what was told to you in comments. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320837/average-value-of-sqrts2-x2-y2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the same thing for the volume integral as you did for the area; convert it to polar coordinates and integrate.  You should have
$$\iint_D f(x,y) \, dA = \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^s r \sqrt{s^2 - r^2} \, dr \, d\theta.$$